# When converting PHP array to JSON array in JavaScript "," becomes the first element of the array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

When i convert my PHP array into a JSON array the first element of the array is empty and it's ",".
Here is my code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: **<?php echo json_encode($d_dates);?>**,
      datasets: [{
      ......
```

I have checked the array in PHP is ok but when i convert it this occurs.

Comment: Try `<?php echo $d_dates;?>,`

Comment: It does not work ,because you have to convert it to some kind of array for JS.You only can get an error when doing that.

Comment: So...have you tried dumping the output of that and seeing if it's valid?

Comment: __json_encode – Returns a string containing the JSON representation of value.__ Hence it is `string/text`, not `array`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
<?php echo json_encode(array_values(array_filter($d_dates)));?>
```

array_filter removes all empty elements in the array